# i performed this code, and got error " TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable"

Tags: python

i performed this code, and got error "  TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable" in line => m[d+1,1] = sum(y[d]*(np.power(x[d],d))).     someone please help

```
d = int(input('Enter the degree of polynomial:  '))
input_file = input('paste input file directory here:  ')

# input_file  sample = s:/sample.txt
inputs = np.loadtxt(input_file , dtype = float, delimiter = ' ')
x = inputs[:,0]
y = inputs[:,1]
m = np.zeros([2,2])
a = np.zeros([2,2])
n = np.zeros([2,2])

while d >=0:
    m[d+1,1] = sum(y[d]*(np.power(x[d],d)))
    a[d+1,1] = a[d,1]
    n[d+1,d+1] = np.array([sum(),sum()])
```

Comment: Without a [mre] that would indicate the data types of the variables in that line, we can only vaguely guess what your issue is.

Comment: One thing that can help debug issues like this: Split the line into multiple steps and verify the output at each step. So instead of `sum(y[d]*(np.power(x[d],d)))`, something like `my_pow=np.power(x[d],d); next_step=y[d]*my_pow;...` and see where the actual error is ocurring.